# Spark "Executor heartbeat timed out"

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple reproducible Spark error. (Spark 2.0 + Amazon EMR 5.0 FYI)

```
def row_parse_function():
    # Custom row parsing function. Details omitted.
    return pyspark.sql.types.Row(...)


if __name__ == "__main__"
    spark_context = build_spark_context("max value bug isolation")
    spark_sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context)

    full_source_path = "s3a://my-bucket/ten_gb_data_file.txt.gz"

    # Tried changing partition parameter to no effect.
    raw_rdd = spark_context.textFile(full_source_path, 5000)
    row_rdd = raw_rdd.map(row_parse_function).filter(bool)
    data_frame = spark_sql_context.createDataFrame(row_rdd, AttribPixelMergedStructType)
    # Tried removing and chaning this repartition call to no effect.
    data_frame.repartition(5000)
    # Removing this cache call makes this small sample work.
    data_frame.cache()
    data_frame_count = data_frame.count()
```

This fails with:

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 5 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 169068 ms
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
```

I know the heartbeat timed out error usually means the worker died, typically due to lack of memory. How do I resolve this?

Comment: What errors are reported on the workers? If you keep your cluster alive after it fails, and access the Spark history server, you should be able to see stderr and stdout for your executors.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the executor and network timeout. Also, it is recommended if you don't have much memory to do persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER) so, if there is not enough memory to cache to save it on disk.

```
--conf spark.network.timeout 10000000 --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000   --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g
```

Comment: Why is `spark.driver.maxResultSize` related to time out error?