# Spark - Executor heartbeat timed out after X ms

Tags: apache-spark

My program read data from files in a directory, the size of these files is 5 GB. I apply many function to these data. I am running spark as standalone (local), on a virtual machine having 32 GB RAM.

The used command :

```
bin/spark-submit --class ripeatlasanalysis.AnalyseTraceroute     --master local --driver-memory 30G  SparkExample-lowprints-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar  1517961600  1518393600 3600
```

the `1517961600  1518393600 3600` are the parameters of jar file.

Sometimes the program run without errors, sometimes not, and the gotten error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due 
 to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent   failure: Lost task 
0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 119, localhost, executor driver):  
ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running   tasks) 
Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 128839 ms
 Driver stacktrace:
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGSchedule  r$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1887)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1875)
```

The question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317625/spark-executor-heartbeat-timed-out) without responses.

Comment: `spark.network.timeout` default value (120s) is usually too low on our production clusters, but it is weird that you experience that on local mode. Did you try to profile the process? could be gc, etc.

Comment: How I can profile the process ? Can you give me a key word to search that

Comment: I usually use jvisualvm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I didn't find much information about your program but in general this can happened due to network issue, or stuck in computation but you can do two stepts. First, *repartition* the *dataframe* you work in more numbers for example `df.repartition(1000)` or you can repartition based on join columns in case of join. You can also increase the maxResultsSize,

Second: you can increase the executor and network timeout.

```
--conf spark.network.timeout 10000000 --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000000   --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g
```

Comment: The idea is to increase the timeout, with little changes : --conf "spark.network.timeout=10000000" instead of  --conf spark.network.timeout 10000000.

Comment: Okay, That’s good. But I think you have a cluster issue. Or data transformation not optimized.

Comment: I am not using a cluster, I run spark in locally. So I should review my code so. I am not using a Dataframe, I am using a Dataset.

Comment: It is not a good idea to increase the spark.executor.heartbeatInterval to 10000000.  That would imply that an executor will send heartbeat every 10000000 milliseconds i.e. every 166 minutes.  Also increasing spark.network.timeout  to 166 minutes is not a good idea either.  The driver will wait 166 minutes before it removes an executor.  You hear beat interval should be way smaller than network timeout.