# Program takes a lot of time to end because of this warning Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the standalone spark cluster with one master and four workers which must read the large oracle table and process it. Each node has 30G Ram. In average program time is about 1.7 Hours, but sometimes it takes a lot of time because of this warning:

```
WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:996)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$heartbeater$1(Executor.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$Lambda$356/321695195.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)
at org.apache.spark.Heartbeater$$anon$1.run(Heartbeater.scala:46)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:293)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
... 14 more
```

I search and added these options to the spark_submit command.But, still receive the same warning.

```
 --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=3600 --conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=1024  --conf spark.rpc.askTimeout=600s
```

Also, I set 28G for driver memory and 24G for executor memory. Moreover, I read this post:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038675/6640504
```

As this comment said, it is not right to increase `spark.network.timeout` and `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` to *10000000* with the same value. I am sure the program takes more time to run with this setting.

Would you please guide me how to solve this problem and improve speed of the program?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This is happening because the executor nodes are trying to get heartbeat response from driver node for the heartbeat request. There can be many reasons behind this, for example - network bandwidth exhausion, network failure, driver node is overwhelmed doing other things. So... check the driver node resources, network bandwidth etc. Increasing the timeout will not help you in any way.

Comment: What sarveshseri said. Plus see if your partition size is too big, then repartition to increase number of partitions and decrease size. This way you break down a big task into many smaller tasks.